# Implementing force logout in linkedin OAuth

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am working with Linkedin oauth for my website.I need to implement Force Logout Concept with linkedin oAuth API.

Below code i have tried, but I can't get the actual solution for force logout with Linkedin oauth.

```
<?php
 include_once "linkedin.php";

    # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
    //$linkedin->debug = true;

    # Now we retrieve a request token. It will be set as $linkedin->request_token
    $linkedInSession = $linkedin->getRequestToken();

    if(empty($linkedInSession))
    {

       $_SESSION['requestToken'] = serialize($linkedin->request_token);

       $url = $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl();

       $loginUrl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout';

       echo("<script>top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>");  
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<script>top.location.href='".$url."'</script>");  
    }
   ?>
```

How do I logout the current logged session in linked account?